# How to configure Electron completely with Vue3 vite project?

Tags: electron, vuejs3, vite, commonjs

I recently integrated Electron into one of my Vue3 project.
And Vue3 project was created by using Vite.
After I configured Electron, it is working properly.
But as Vue3 project supports ESM while Electron only supports CommonJS module, I can see red underline in commonJS feature.
Here I attached screenshot.
Is it something because of linting or I am thinking wrong?
Even I can see those red lines, app is working properly.
Not sure what is the reason.
Please let me know and correct me.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Issue Image]